# Put elements over clipped div without hiding

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I am trying to achieve something like this:
[image]

I am using clip-path to shape the background, but it causes the items not to be shown. I found something about linear-gradient hacks but I see the result is kinda "low quality", the border is very much pixelated. Any workaround? I tried `overflow: visible;` and `z-index: 1;`

HTML:

```
<div class="background">
    <ul class="btn-group">
        <li class="btn-group-item">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="btn-group-item">
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="btn-group-item">
            <a href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background {
    background: #3f3f3f;
    clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 75%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 43%);
}
.btn-group {
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
}
.btn-group-item {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: apply the clip-path to a pseudo element, ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65415078/8620333

Comment: Why don't you simply use SVG to draw the polygon, instead of trying to come up with a complex CSS solution?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue last time. You cannot do it no matter what you try as long as `.btn-group` ***ul*** in within the clipped div.

You should write `.btn-group` *ul* outside of the container div and use `position:absolute` property.

```css
.background {
    background: #3f3f3f;
    clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 75%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 43%);
    position:relative;
  height:300px;
}
.btn-group {
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:-3rem;
}
.btn-group-item {
    background: black;
    color: white;
     margin:1rem;
       
}

a{
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  height:100px;
  width:180px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="background">
    
</div>
  <ul class="btn-group">
        <li class="btn-group-item">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="btn-group-item">
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="btn-group-item">
            <a href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: Use `left:` and `top:` properties of `position:absolute` on the `.btn-group` ul as per your requirement

Comment: What if there is content above and i don't know the height?

Comment: Above what :) Essay97

Comment: This is what I was working on the last time. https://i.imgur.com/5CM6bRV.jpg. You may pseudo class to do it.

Comment: Just give me some time, I will share you the trick :)

Comment: I think somehow above has already pointed this out. Yes I have used pseudo element for my clip-path. :)

Comment: I mean, above the content I posted in the image there is a paragraph, but I don't know the length since it is dynamically generated. I don't understand what you mean by saying "you may use pseudo class", I'm pretty new to web dev

Comment: O Dear. Is it not done yet :) ... Shall I help you